# Put custom image on camera preview in android

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-camera-intent

I went through lots of link but still confuse, here is the problem.
I am trying to put some cartoon images while opening a camera preview in android.
Please suggest me the way to do so.

Comment: You can put ImageView above the previewView and when camera is opened just hide it.

Comment: Search for augmented reality ...

Comment: @MaximMetelskiy: I want to capture photo with that custom images.

Comment: Capture the photo into a Bitmap, draw the custom images on the Bitmap, save the Bitmap?